# How do I check the device for support

Tags: wireless-networking

I have windows 10 (disc upgraded from 8)windows 10 is running fine until I try to add my wireless printer. CD installed cannot detect printer and tells me to check device supports IEEE802.11n IEEE802.11g or IEEE802.11b. If device is set to 11n only WEP or TKIP cannot be used and to change security protocol. Can anyone help please

Comment: What make and model of Printer?

Comment: Printer is Canon PixmaMG3550

Comment: Download and install the latest driver for Windows 10.....https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg3550.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Windows%2010%20(64-bit)